# Card Game without using arrays

Tags: c#

We have a task to create a random hand of cards (5 cards). Where the cards can not be the same. We have yet not learnd how to use arrays so it would be nice if anyone could help us to get started without using arrays.

This is how we have started, but we can not figure out how to not get the same card twice.

```
static void Cards()
{
     var rnd = new Random();
     var suit, rank, count = 0;

     while (count < 5)
     { 
         rank = rnd.Next(13) + 1;
         suit = rnd.Next(4) + 1;
         if (suit == 1)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Spader " + rank);
         }
         else if (suit == 2)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Hjärter " + rank);
         }
         else if (suit == 3)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Ruter " + rank);
         }
         else
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Klöver " + rank);
         }
         count++;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Detta är inte ett ställe för dina läxor
2) Skriv all er kod på engelska, det som presenteras för användaren skall självklart vara lokaliserat men hur ska icke-svenskar förstå vad ni gör?
3) StackOverflow finns inte till för att göra er läxa åt er.
4) Använd inte prefix (iFarg) i variabelnamn!

Comment: @Zache English please.. :)

Comment: It's telling them in their own language to use english for everyones understanding :)

Comment: Though this won't directly answer the question, I do believe given the problem it's something you definitely need to read. http://superuser.com/a/712583/152345

Comment: I think you can use in this case 5 variables for generating cards instead array. And then start to learn arrays, lists, dictionaries, hashsets and other collections.

Comment: @Zache We don´t want you guys to do the whole code! We are beginners trying to understand programming. We just want a little push in the right direction!

Comment: Have you learned about collections?  Cause without some kind of collection (or array), it'll be rather more complicated than a beginner should have to deal with.  Like, say, using a `long` as a bitmask of what cards have been dealt.

Comment: If you can't use arrays, or any other list type structure, then you'll simply have to declare five sets of variables to hold the cards such as `suit1`, `rank1`, `suit2`, `rank2`, etc.  Then you'll have to literally hard-code a series of checks to make sure each new random card doesn't conflict with the other already created cards.  Use a `switch` statement and the `count` variable so you know which variables have a card in them already.  It's horribly efficient, but that is sometimes the way beginning courses are taught.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of problem that arrays can deal with, so it would be easier to learn how to use them. Without them you need to store your 5 cards in variables (string card1, string card2, etc) then on each iteration check to see if the card matches any of these and discard it if it does, else save it. But then you have a whole bunch of conditional code to see which variable to store it in...

Much easier to just have an array

```
string[] cards = new string[5];
```

then you can just loop over the array looking for a match (something like this)

```
for(int idx=0; idx<5; idx++){
  if(cards[idx]==thecardyouhavejustcreatedwithrandomcode){
    break; //bail out of the for on a match
  }
  cards[iAntalKort]=thecardyouhavejustcreatedwithrandomcode;
}
```